# How can i convert the C# code listed below into VB

Tags: json.net, c#-to-vb.net

i am using the Json.net to serialize an object. the specific object is eventInstance.Properties which is the properties of a windows event log.

i am  getting a

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Self referencing loop detected for property
```

for C# an example is shown here

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(joe, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
 {
     ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
 });
```

my line of code is below but i am not sure how to make it work in VB or if it is even possible

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f18", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(eventInstance.Properties(), New JsonSerializerSettings() {ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore}))
```

i get an error that states 'ReferenceLoopHandling' is an enum type and cannot be used as an expression

thanks for the help

Comment: you're missing a `With` and a period before the property; if I remember right:  `New JsonSerializerSettings() With { .ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore}`

Comment: thanks that worked, of the three code converters i tried online none  had the correct result  for this to work

Answer (score -1):

You can use below code:

```
    Private Function getJSON(sJSON As String) As String
Dim objNews = New List(Of News)()
Dim news = New News()
news.id = ""
news.title = "blah"
Dim lst = New List(Of Object)()
lst.Add(New With {.video_identifier = "id1"})
lst.Add(New With {.video_identifier = "id2"})
news.video_identifier = lst.ToArray()
objNews.Add(news)
Return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(New With {.data = objNews})
End Function

Class News

Public Property title As String
    Get
        Return _title
    End Get

    Set
        _title = value
    End Set
End Property

Private _title As String

Private _sId As String

Public Property id As String
    Get
        Return _sId
    End Get

    Set
        _sId = value
    End Set
End Property

Private _youtube_videos As Object() = New List(Of Object)().ToArray()

Public Property video_identifier As Object()
    Get
        Return _youtube_videos
    End Get

    Set
        _youtube_videos = value
    End Set
End Property
End Class

Public Class YoutubeVideos

Private _video_identifier As String

Public Property video_identifier As String
    Get
        Return _video_identifier
    End Get

    Set
        _video_identifier = value
    End Set
End Property
End Class
```

Comment: You should explain *why* this block of code solves the issue with the `ReferenceLoopHandling`